# Using HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath on nested information

Tags: perl, html-content-extraction

Imagine an HTML page that is a report with repetitive structure:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Big Hairy Report Page</h1>

    <div class="customer">
      <div class="customer_id">001</div>
      <div class="customer_name">Joe Blough</div>
      <div class="customer_addr">123 That Road</div>
      <div class="customer_city">Smallville</div>
      <div class="customer_state">Nebraska</div>
      <div class="order_info">
        <div class="shipping_details">
          <ul>
             <li>Large crate</li>
             <li>Fragile</li>
             <li>Express</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="order_item">Deluxe Hoodie</div>
        <div class="payment">35.95</div>
        <div class="order_id">000123456789</div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">StackOverflow rocks!</div>
    </div>

   <div class="customer">
     <div class="customer_id">002</div>
 ....  and so forth for a list of 150 customers
```

This kind of report page appears often.  My goal is to extract each customer's related information into some reasonable data structure using [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath).

I know to do the basics and get the file read into $tree.  But how can one concisely loop through that tree and get associated clusters of information per each customer?  How, for example, would I create a list of address labels sorted by customer number based on this information?  What if I want to sort all my customer information by state?

I'm not asking for the whole perl (I can read my file, output to file, etc).  I just need help understanding how to ask HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath for those bundles of related data, and then how to dereference them.  If it's easier to express this in terms of an output statement (i.e., Joe Blough ordered 1 Deluxe Hoodie and left 1 comment) then that's cool, too.

Thank you very much for those of you who tackle this one, it seems a bit overwhelming to me.

Comment: Wow-thanks so much - the hard problem now is to decide which answer to upvote! Thanks for the fast responses, Gangabass, Borodin, and ikegami.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you need.

It starts by pulling all the `<div class="customer">` elements into array `@customers` and extracting the information from there.

I have taken your example of the address label, sorted by the customer number (by which I assume you mean the field with `class="customer_id"`). All of the address values are pulled from the array into the hash `%customers`, keyed by the customer ID and the name of the element class. The information is then printed in the order of the ID.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_file('html.html');

my @customers = $tree->findnodes('/html/body/div[@class="customer"');

my %customers;
for my $cust (@customers) {
  my $id = $cust->findvalue('div[@class="customer_id"]');
  for my $field (qw/ customer_name customer_addr customer_city customer_state /) {
    my $xpath = "div[\@class='$field']";
    my $val = $cust->findvalue($xpath);
    $customers{$id}{$field} = $val;
  }
}

for my $id (sort keys %customers) {

  my $info = $customers{$id};

  print "Customer ID $id\n";
  print $info->{customer_name}, "\n";
  print $info->{customer_addr}, "\n";
  print $info->{customer_city}, "\n";
  print $info->{customer_state}, "\n";
  print "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Customer ID 001
Joe Blough
123 That Road
Smallville
Nebraska
```

Comment: Thank you Borodin for this answer. The nested structure matches up to the way I am thinking about this issue very well, the perl is concise, and the field list will be simple to change in the case where the div classes of the report change or are extended.  One further refinement would be to ask, What if we only want to print the "Fragile" shipments onto a different kind of label?  Those sub-fields don't have classes assigned.  I'll work on that and post a different question if I get stuck.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Borodin never extracts that information. Using mine, you can use `for my $customer (@customers) { if (grep $_ eq 'Fragile', @{ $customer->{order_info}{shipping_details} }) { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

I'll use [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML) since it's faster and I'm familiar with it, but it should be pretty straightforward to convert what I post to from XML::LibXML to HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath if you so desire.

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

sub get_text { defined($_[0]) ? $_[0]->textContent() : undef }

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_html(...);

my @customers;
for my $cust_node ($doc->findnodes('/html/body/div[@class="customer"]')) {
   my $id   = get_text( $cust_node->findnodes('div[@class="customer_id"]') );
   my $name = get_text( $cust_node->findnodes('div[@class="customer_name"]') );
   ...
   push @customers, {
      id   => $id,
      name => $name,
      ...
   };
}
```

---

Actually, given the regularity of the data, you don't have to hardcode the field names.

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

sub parse_list {
   my ($node) = @_;
   return [
      map parse_field($_),
       $node->findnodes('li')
   ];
}

sub parse_field {
   my ($node) = @_;
   my @children = $node->findnodes('*');
   return $node->textContent() if !@children;
   return parse_list($children[0]) if $children[0]->nodeName() eq 'ul';
   return {
      map { $_->getAttribute('class') => parse_field($_) }
       @children
   };
}

{
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_html( ... );
   my @customers =
      map parse_field($_),
       $doc->findnodes('/html/body/div[@class="customer"]');

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ikegami, for an excellent answer, including the abstracted version.  I may write the tool I am building to use variables for the field names so that it is easy to change if the page structure changes.

Comment: ikegami, as I try your variant, I have found that I must hard-code the path within the tree to the div I seek.  What if the page is variable, or complex, and the /html/body/path/down/tree/to/div is unknown or uncertain?  Is there a way to use your answer if that path is unknown but the div class containing the information is consistently known?  (i.e., class="customer" can occur anywhere in the page?)  Thanks, this is an interesting version of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
...

my @customers;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $mech->content() );

foreach my $customer_section_node ( $tree->findnodes('//div[ @class = "customer" ]') ) {

   my $customer = {};
   $customer->{id} = find_customer_id($customer_section_node);
   $customer->{name} = find_customer_name($customer_section_node);
   ...
   push @customers, $customer;
}

$tree->delete();

sub find_customer_id {
    my $node = shift;

    my ($id) = $node->findvalues('.//div[ @class = "customer_id" ]');
    return $id
}
```

Comment: Thank you, gangabass.  This answer works well.  I did ultimately select Borodin's answer because his more closely answers the example I wrote, but this version does work for me also.